# convert ipad app to run on iphone (universal app)

Tags: iphone, ipad, universal-binary

I have a working iPad app which I now need to make work on iPhone. I've been reading around a fair bit on this, but haven't found a good answer. On this site, I saw some discussion... but again, no definite answers.

Does anyone know of any tutorials? I have captured in my code whether it's an ipad or not - so it's all ready - I just need to actually get it on my iphone to test!

Thanks for any info

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at this article
[Converting iPhone apps to universal](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/04/converting-iphone-apps-to-universal.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

actualy you just have to change TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY in project settings to run app on bouth devices. Everything else is just alot of if's :)

Comment: done that - thanks! I also now have a bunch of "if IPAD"... type of queries.