# How to create app it's work well for multiple device (iPhone and iPad) in xcode 5?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, storyboard, xcode5

I'm new in iOS.

Now my app work well for iPad.

I want my app work well for both(iPhone and iPad).

How to do that?

Comment: Autolayout & multiple storyboards.

Comment: Different resolution images. Also being able to utilize Google before knowing how to programming is very helpful

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make an iPad app Universal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382394/make-an-ipad-app-universal)

Comment: @nhgrif if i create multiple storyboards How and Where i switch between storyboards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use story board for now and link everything together.  Google how to use storyboard it is pretty straight forward.